# Create a Safari-like back/forward button?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I to create two buttons that are joined together like the back and forward buttons in Safari.  I've tried looking on the internet for any information for creating buttons like that but to no avail.

Here's what I want:

[image: Safari buttons]

Comment: which back/forward buttons do you mean?

Comment: The safari kind where the buttons are like joint together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a look at using an [NSSegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSegmentedControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html).